# How to mimic Golang make() function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, go

I am trying to rewrite go code to python and I don't understand how the `make()` function in Golang works.

As an example I have this code which I'm trying to rewrite to Python:

```
a = make([]string, 1)
b = make([]int, 1)
c = make(map[string]string)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you'd want to do with the result of a `make` equivalent?

Comment: @kingkupps I don't really know because I can't understand what it does ...

Comment: What does the rest of your go code look like? Can you also post any Python code you've attempted to write?

Comment: It depends on what you do with the slice later. There isn't a close equivalent in vanilla python but you may find things like numpy and pandas do similar things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to `make` anything in Python... or in other words, no need to write a function that mimics `make`. Unlike Go where you have to be explicit about allocating something, in Python this is implicit as objects are allocated automatically on creation for you.

- `a = make([]string, 1)`: this is a slice of `string` of size 1 and capacity 1, in Python you can just create an empty list instead: `a = []` and then `.append()` strings into it. Unlike Go for slices or arrays, Python does not require all elements of a list to be of the same type. If you want you could create `a = [None]` just to be able to index the list right away (in general `a = [default_value] * size`).
- `b = make([]int, 1)`: same here, just `b = []` or `b = [0]` if you need to index the list right away. Note that Go initializes all elements to `0` for `[]int`.
- `c = make(map[string]string)`: this creates a map with `string` as keys and values. Closest thing in Python would be a dictionary: `c = {}`. And again, you are not constrained by types in Python so you can later do `c["foo"] = "bar"` without a problem.

---

**NOTE THAT** Go slices have different semantics than Python slices. Doing `a[1:10]` in Go creates a slice that is merely a *view* on the underlying object, while in Python `a[1:10]` potentially *copies* all the elements in the range creating a *new* object (this is true for the built-in `list` and `tuple`).

Comment: Great answer, but to be clear, you can't generally equate a python list to a go slice. Go slices refer to a single underlying data structure but python slices frequently copy.

Comment: @tdelaney ah, right those created through `make` are actually slices in Go, thanks.

Comment: "Go slices have different semantics than Python slices. Doing a[1:10] in Go creates a slice that is merely a view on the underlying object, while in Python a[1:10] copies all the elements creating a new list." So, the semantics of slicing in Python is defined by the *type* involved not the language. Built-in python containers do create copies, which is incidentally true, but for example, slicing `numpy.ndarray`'s will result in views.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `s/copies/potentially copies/` I guess :') thanks